# Oracle APEX Error : Page Protection Viiolation

Tags: oracle, session, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

Page protection violation: This may be caused by submitting a page that had not yet finished loading or by manual alteration of protected page items. For further assistance, please contact the application administrator.

Getting this error in Oracle APEX Version 20.2

Please let me know if anyone can help on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, there's a **hidden** item on a page whose **Value protected** property is turned `ON`. So, turn it `OFF` (or don't manually alter its value).

Comment: yes agreed. All the hidden items have their Value Protected set to NO already.
and if it is set to YES, that  causes session state  protection violation and I am getting Page protection violation error.
Thanks.